# open read file with file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, file, posix, file-descriptor

I use a driver that have many files, each file I have an ID to it, when I open theses files I store the files descriptors in strcut array that contain the ID with the file descriptor, each opened file can be blocking or not.

I want to read the file from another program or from an other function in the program, when I try to read a blocking file with its file descriptor, it don't still blocking until I write on it, it return no data in the buffer, but when I use it in the same function It still blocking.

Where is the problem ?

```
if (vg_bufObj[indice].protocolType == _NO_BLOC) 
vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd = open(d_path, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
else
vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd = open(d_path, O_RDONLY);
```

vg_bufObj is struct and declared extern

in other function I read the file with

```
read_size = read(vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd, data, 8);
```

When the protocolType  is specified _BLOC the file is open blocking, but when I read it from the another function it return empty data and the read size return the max value of the variable.

Comment: Paste your code - without it it's difficult to help

Comment: the code just a simple open and read, it is below

Answer (score 0):

```
if (vg_bufObj[indice].protocolType == _NO_BLOC) 
vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd = open(d_path, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
else
vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd = open(d_path, O_RDONLY);
```

vg_bufObj is struct and declared extern

in other function I read the file with

```
read_size = read(vg_bufObj[indice].dev_fd, data, 8);
```

When the protocolType  is specified _BLOC the file is open blocking, but when I read it from the another function it return empty data and the read size return the max value of the variable.